# SySam service and powerbuilder 12.0 is not getting started on windows server 2008

Tags: powerbuilder

We have powerbuilder12.0 installed on Windows server 2008. We also have a standalone served license for powerbuilder12.0. Initially powerbuilder was working fine but now whenever we try to open PB, we get a license error. When we checked on lmtools borrowing tab, it showed expiration date was finished. Can anyone please advice on how to re-borrow powerbuilder license using lmtools.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for PB 12 states it is only supported for runtime use on Windows Server 2008.  Not for development.  So that could be a problem right there.

Sybase® PowerBuilder version 12.0 supports these operating systems:

```
Microsoft Windows XP with Service Pack 3
Microsoft Windows XP Tablet PC Edition with Service Pack 3
Microsoft Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 2
Microsoft Windows Vista Business Edition with Service Pack 2
Microsoft Windows 7 Professional 32-bit
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 with Service Pack 2 (support for deployment)
```

PowerBuilder 12.0 builds 32-bit applications, but supports deployed applications in both 32-bit and 64-bit environments on the Vista operating system. For information about using PowerBuilder help on the Vista operating system, see "Using Windows Help files on Vista" in the PowerBuilder Users Guide.

Comment: We use the server for building powerbuilder application using orcascript commands. All the builds were created properly until borrow expiration date mentioned in borrowing tab of lmtools. But since the borrow expiration date has gone, we are getting the license errors for PB on server. Kindly advice us on how to reborrow the license of powerbuilder using lmtools.